# Spring Security - permit only requests with prefix

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I need to secure all rest endpoints in our Resource Server except endpoints that start with `/unsecured`. So requests like the following should be permitted to everyone:

- `/unsecured/foo/bar`
- `/unsecured`
- ...

but requests like these:

- `/foo/unsecured/bar`
- `/foo/bar`
- ...

should require authentication.

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class OAuth2ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity security) throws Exception {
        security
            .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests -> {
                authorizeRequests.antMatchers("unsecured/**").permitAll();
                authorizeRequests.anyRequest().authenticated();
            });
    }
}
```

But in the configuration above, all endpoints require authentication.

This is response which I receive when I tried access to unsecured endpoint:

code 401

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}
```

Comment: Don't you want `authorizeRequests.antMatchers("unsecured/**").permitAll();`

Comment: @AlanHay Yes I am sorry, I just bad copied my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

premitAll() is what you are looking for. Looks like you were just missing the / before the URL

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class OAuth2ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity security) throws Exception {
        security
            .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests - > {
                authorizeRequests.antMatchers("/unsecured/**").permitAll();
                authorizeRequests.anyRequest().authenticated();
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: I am really sorry. I bad copied my code. I already have permitAll() on first line.

Comment: maybe you need the "/" before unsecured?

Comment: Yes, it works but is weird. Thank you. You can update answer and I will mark it as answer